# Ошибка «undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.getBoundingClientRect')»

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код, который возвращает ошибку

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.getBoundingClientRect')

в консоль... Бьюсь целый день... Помогите...

```
function actSect () {
    var sect = document.querySelectorAll('.m-item'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i <= sect.length; i++) {
        var elem = sect[i],
            top = sect[i].getBoundingClientRect().top,
            bot = sect[i].getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
            elemH = sect[i].offsetHeight,
            winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        if (top < winH/2 && top > 0) {
            if (!elem.classList.contains('-active')) {
                elem.classList.add('-active');
            }
        } else if (bot > 0 && bot < winH/2 || top > winH) {
            if (elem.classList.contains('-active')) {
                elem.classList.remove('-active');
            }
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', actSect);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас неправильное условие в цикле — нестрогое сравнение `i <= sect.length` вместо правильного строгого `i < sect.length`.

Замените строчку

```
for (i = 0; i <= sect.length; i++) {
```

на

```
for (i = 0; i < sect.length; ++i) {
```

Comment: Спасибо)) надо спать больше))

Comment: @АнтонГолубков, не за что)